# What are some SAS-70 Type II data centers in the Boston area?

Tags: hosting

I work at a small company that is going for ISO certification, and as a part of that we need to have our servers in a SAS-70 data center.  Could anyone make some recommendations *besides* Hosted Solutions in Charlestown (we're familiar with those guys and they are... sub-optimal for a variety of reasons)?

Comment: What ISO certification are you shooting for?  It's unrelated to the question, but we are also looking at what auditing standards and certifications our company should be targeting.

Answer (score 1):

[Vericenter](http://www.vericenter.com/data_centers/boston/index.aspx) has a SAS 70 Type II-compliant facility in Boston.

Answer (score 0):

[Navisite](http://www.navisite.com) has a SAS 70 Type II-compliant datacenter in Andover.

I'd stay away from them. They were expensive and not at all responsive.

Answer (score 0):

Savvis BO2/BO3 is compliant.

Answer (score 0):

You may also want to take a look at [2nPlus1](http://2nplus1.com/), it's a pretty new facility on the sommerville/cambridge line (on mcgrath highway).

Answer (score 0):

[Sungard](http://www.availability.sungard.com/sungardsolutions/ITSolutions/consulting/datacenter/Pages/datacenteranditservices.aspx) is great. We use them for all but one of our Datacenters and that's only because they don't have a presence in Australia.

Answer (score 0):

ColoSpace has six (6) SAS 70 Type II Data Centers throughout New England.  Competitive pricing, responsive customer service and exceptional engineering/technical support.
Somerville, Waltham, Rockland, Marlborough, Bedford,NH and Manchester, NH.